# Calculating line integral along a circle

Tags: calculus

The vector field $\mathbf G$ and a curve $X$ is defined below : 
$$\mathbf G(x,y)=\dfrac{(2x-y,x+2y)}{x^2+y^2},\qquad X(t)=(2\cos{3t},2\sin{3t}),\qquad 0\leq t\leq2\pi$$
I want to calculate the line integral :
$$\int_X \mathbf G \cdot d\mathbf s$$
My solution starts at decomposing $\mathbf G$ :
$$\mathbf G=\dfrac{(-y,x)}{x^2+y^2}+\dfrac{2(x,y)}{x^2+y^2}=\mathbf F_1+\mathbf F_2$$
$\mathbf F_1$ is not conservative on $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ and when integrate along some circle, value should be $2\pi$.
$\mathbf F_2$ is conservative and since $X$ is a closed curve, the integral should be zero.

Since we integrate 3 times along a circle, the answer should be $6\pi$.

Is the solution above correct? Is $X$ really a closed curve and can I proceed like above?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be correct, though you didn't show your work.

Comment: $X$ is a closed curve.  It is completely legitimate to break $G$ into its conservative and not conservative components.  It is a small leap to jump to the integral of $F_1$  but only a small leap.  And the answer is correct.

Comment: @DougM Many thanks!